# setInputType with ID 4096 is ignored by program

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a slider that let's me dynamically add a number of EditText fields.

This is the code I use:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
editText.setId(i);
editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
editText.setInputType(4096);
linearLayout.addView(editText);
editText.setHint("Cash Flow " + i);
i++;
```

This is in a while loop that makes sure the number of fields created = number on the slider. Anyways, the setInputType according to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL) doesn't work for all values. For example, if I put 2 in it, it will automatically have the keyboard only as the "number&signs" portion.

However, I need the person to be able to enter negative numbers (i.e. a negative sign before the number).

I figured TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED with the ID 4096 should do the trick, but I can still enter letters and stuff in the field...

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED is a flag and not a input type,what you must do is write it like this:

```
setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense :) thanks, will accept as soon as the time limit passed. it works perfectly now :)

Comment: Glad i could help :) bit type flags are confusing for a lot of people